# Error installing basemap on mac

Tags: python, gcc, matplotlib

I followed these steps to install the GEOS libraries ([source](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html#installation) ). I successfully installed the GEOS library. My problem is in the following step:

1. cd back to the top level basemap directory (basemap-X.Y.Z) and
   run the usual 'python setup.py install'.  Check your installation
   by running "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap" at the python
   prompt.

When I run the setup.py file I get the following error:

```
distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Isrc -c nad2bin.c -o nad2bin.o" failed with exit status 127
```

Im working with a Mac with OS version 10.9.2.
I have installed the gcc compiler through the command line tools package in Xcode.
My gcc compiler info:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: is using conda an options?

Comment: if I use conda package manager, that means I have to re-install all the packages in the Anaconda environment?

Comment: yes, but it's **so** much easier. `conda create --name basemap_env basemap` and you're done. it'll take care of the dependencies for you.

Comment: ok I installed conda and simply added it to the PATH variable so I didn't have to re-install any packages. so I followed your suggestion and created the basemap_env. I activated and proceeded to test. But I got an error stating that I have no module named basemap installed. I'm calling the module the standard way: `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

Comment: it doesn't work that way. start fresh with a new environment. trust me. conda will do all the installing for you.